# Different URLs in category and product page in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm new in Prestashop and I've got annoying problem.

Here is url for the product:

https://fine.net/category/3-product.html
And it's fine.

But for the category page i've got:
https://fake.net/3-category

I know that I can't remove the number, but I want to add that number to product page like in category page.

I want to have: 
https://fake.net/3-category/3-product.html

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible within the default features. You can try to change your URLs in admin panel **Configure->Shop Parameters->Traffic & SEO-> SEO & URLs->Schema of URLs** and find **Route to products**, but, unfortunately, by default, you can use only that keywords which are listed below the field and there is no category_id field. So to reach this you need to override some classes like Dispatcher, Link and maybe more or you can get [some module](https://addons.prestashop.com/) which will do this for you